# Read values from properties file placed in unix machine?

Tags: java, unix

I have placed a properties file in below location. i created a folder in root and placed a properties file there.

```
/someFolder/some.properties
```

Now through java i need read properties using Properties class. can i give path as below?

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.load(new FileInputStream("/someFolder/some.properties")); OR
```

props.load(new FileInputStream("/someFolder//some.properties"));

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try it? What's the path of your file? Does it contain double slashes? Then why would you want to use double slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can give the path as in the first example and the second example will also work though there is no requirement for the `//`. You may has seen paths using `\\`, as the `\` character requires escaping in string literals but the `/` does not require escaping.

Instead of hard-coding the path into the code, consider specifying the path via a property (or some other configuration setting):

> java -Dmy.property.file=/someFolder/some.properties com.mine.MyApplication

Then access the path via `System.getProperty("my.property.file");`.